# Cordova back button is not working on the first launch of android app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, back-button

I am using Cordova 6.x to build Android app(6.0). I have overridden the back button functionality using event listener. But this event listener is called on the first time launch of the app. But if I kill the app and relaunch, this event listener is called on pressing back button.

index.html

```
...
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">
...
```

app.js

```
...
angular.module('app', []).controller("appController", function($scope) {

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady()
    {
       console.log("On device ready called");
       document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBackButton, false);
    }

    function onBackButton()
    {
         console.log("Back button pressed");   
    }
});
...
```

When I first time launch the app after installation, log has "On device ready called". But if I relaunch the app and press back button, log has "On device ready called" as well as "Back button pressed".
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html) says _The deviceready event behaves somewhat differently from others. Any event handler registered after the deviceready event fires has its callback function called immediately._

Comment: But pressing back button should fire the "backbutton" event. And hence handler "onBackButton" should be called which is not happening on the first time launch of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try manually bootstrap angular and see if backbutton function works correctly. 
So, something like...

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, "YourApp"); 
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBackButton, false);

    function onBackButton()
    {
       console.log("Back button pressed");   
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: It worked but broke lot of things(as states were lost). Cordova doesn't support native activity with cordova activity.